# While using SceneKit an animation pauses or stops other actions and animation for a short time

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

When I run this animation for the first time whole actions pause nearly 0.5s or couple of frames.

This spoils the application and very irritating.

When this animation called later it never effects other scene and works just fine.

```
SCNTransaction.begin()
  SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 3.0
  hunts[i].m.transparency = 1
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

I call the func under following function once like the other animations depend on
some logic.

```
func renderer(_ renderer:SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time:TimeInterval) {

}
```

Comment: Does the animation start right out of the gate, like the first appearance of hunts[i] starts animating right away as soon as they are shown?

Comment: No, Actually it starts after  20 seconds scene view showing other animations as action. Before that animation more than 100 actions run fluently fired every 0.15 seconds in renderer. I found temp solution to get rid of the problem at the moment. I run that animation once just after scene view activated after that if it is called does not cause problem but I am at the beginning of developing this app I must find the reason.

Comment: It is weird because once it is called and finished running recalling does not make the frame skip. I noticed, at first call rendering takes very long part of frame processing.

Comment: Yeah - it's like it's 'caching' it or something.  I had some similar problems which is why I commented.  I ended up preloading all my models and I prebuilt actions and sequences offline too.  Once I did that, things seem to work better.